# Laravel form validation max chars using 2 fields

Tags: laravel, validation

i have a simple registeration form i use this validation for creating u new user

```
   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'first_name' => ['required'],
        'last_name' => ['required'],
        'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', ],
        
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Errors!','errors'=>$validator->errors()], 500);
    }else{
        return response()->json(['message' => 'User registered successfully'], 201);

    }
```

now  i need to make a vidation rule to combine last and first name together and  validate max chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would first add the full_name entry to the request object, and then i would validate with the built in validation rules (either max or between).

```
$request->request->add(['full_name' => $request->input('first_name').' '.$request->input('last_name')]);

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'first_name' => ['required'],
    'last_name' => ['required'],
    'full_name' => ['max:10'],//or between:6,10
    'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
    'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', ],
    
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Errors!','errors'=>$validator->errors()], 500);
}else{
    return response()->json(['message' => 'User registered successfully'], 201);

}
```

Comment: works like charm and very simple Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Write Laravel [Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\DataAwareRule;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class FullNameMaxCharactor implements ValidationRule, DataAwareRule
{
    protected $requestData=null;
    /**
     * Run the validation rule.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(string): \Illuminate\Translation\PotentiallyTranslatedString  $fail
     */
    public function validate(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail): void
    {


        $fullNameCharacters= Str::length(data_get($this->requestData,'first_name').data_get($this->requestData,'last_name'));


        if ($fullNameCharacters>10) {

            $fail('The first and last name should be less than equal to 10.');
        }

    }

    public function setData(array $data)
    {
       $this->requestData=$data;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and in the validation rule

```
 $validation=\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'first_name' => ['required',new \App\Rules\FullNameMaxCharactor()],
        'last_name' => ['required'],
        'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    ]);
```

Comment: sounds right but the answer i marked right more simple thanks i'll use this in other complex task i need also